# Changing the delimiter in SAS

Tags: csv, sas

I have a text file and I want to change the delimiter from comma to pipe (|). Here is what the data file look like-

```
P0020016,450.05,20150818000000,24.1,140,1
P0020016,450.05,20150818010000,24.1,140,1
P0020016,450.05,20150818020000,24.1,140,1
```

How can I change the commas to pipe in SAS? I tried using ODS CSV but it did not work. Thanks!

Comment: Please include an example of the code you use to export this, as there are multiple ways you may have done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use a simple `DATA _NULL` to make that change.

```
data _null_;
  length x1-x6 $200 ;
  infile 'old.csv' dsd dlm=',' truncover ;
  file 'new.pipe' dsd dlm='|' ;
  input x1-x6 ;
  put x1-x6;
run;
```

You could make the `6` into a macro variable. You could even add a step to read the first line and count how many columns there are and set the macro variable. You can change the length of the character variables you read the data into if $200 is too short.

Comment: @Tom-Thank a lot Tom! Your code worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're looking for but this might help:

```
data test;
text = "P0020016,450.05,20150818000000,24.1,140,1";
text2 = tranwrd(text,',','|');
run;
```

Comment: Don't try to answer a question that's unclear - clarify it first.  Given that, this clearly _doesn't_ answer the question, as the user is trying to output a dataset to a text file.

Answer (score -1):

I would read the file into a dataset, then export with the DATA step below.

This will export your file and declare your delimiter as "|" (or whatever other character you want to specify)

```
DATA _NULL_;
FILE "path.txt" DLM = '|' TERMSTR=CRLF;
SET have;
IF _N_ = 1 THEN 
PUT 'var1,var2,var3';
PUT var1 var2 var3;
RUN;
```

CRLF will make sure it does not create one long row.